# entity records not updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following method:

```
public static void UpdatePpsTransaction(IEnumerable<PpsTransaction> ppsTransaction)
{
  using (var context = PpsEntities.DefaultConnection())
  {
    foreach (var trans in ppsTransaction)
    {
      context.PpsTransactions.Attach(trans);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

}

I was removing these records but I ended up creating a field IsProcessed which I am now setting to true. Now I am updating the records instead of deleting them, keeping them for record keeping.

Anyhow, I am not getting any errors but it is not updating the record.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not telling EF that you have made any changes, try to use the Entry method, on your Context:

```
public static void UpdatePpsTransaction(IEnumerable<PpsTransaction> ppsTransaction)
{
  using (var context = PpsEntities.DefaultConnection())
  {
    foreach (var trans in ppsTransaction)
    {
      context.Entry(trans).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

This way, the entities will be attached to the context in a modified stated, so when you call `SaveChanges()`, these will be saved.

This will only work if the entities already exists in the database, which they should.

Comment: So I don't need to attach by doing it this away?

Comment: No, setting the State to modified will attach it for you.

Answer (score 0):

From msdn:

> If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but which is not currently 
>   being tracked by the context then you can tell the context to track
>   the entity using the Attach method on DbSet. The entity will be in the
>   Unchanged state in the context. Note that no changes will be made to the
>   database if SaveChanges is
>   called without doing any other manipulation of the attached entity.
>   This is because the entity is in the Unchanged state.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) is the link